# MS Sql: Produce multiple tables excluding some rows each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Lets suppose that I have a table of employees that each belongs to only one department.

I need to write a query in ms sql that i will be able to produce multiple tables and in each table i want to exclude the employees from one department.

i.e.

```
John   IT
Helen  HR
Doris  IT
Peter  SALES
Paul   SALES
Joane  HR
```

Result:

```
Helen  HR     not it
Peter  SALES  not it
Paul   SALES  not it
Joane  HR     not it

John   IT     not hr
Doris  IT     not hr
Peter  SALES  not hr
Paul   SALES  not hr

John   IT   not sales
Helen  HR   not sales
Doris  IT   not sales
Joane  HR   not sales
```

Can you please help me produce this result. Thanks in advance.

I do not need many tables in the result. Just one like the above.

Comment: One query returns one result table, never more, never less.

Comment: I don't need different tables in the result. I will add a column for example "not it" in each exclusion. I corrected the above. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, do a `UNION ALL`:

```
select emp, dep, 'not it' from tablename where dep <> 'IT'
UNION ALL
select emp, dep, 'not hr' from tablename where dep <> 'HR'
UNION ALL
select emp, dep, 'not sales' from tablename where dep <> 'SALES'
```

More general answer, do a `SELF JOIN`:

```
select t1.emp, t1.dep, 'not ' || t2.dep
from tablename t1
  join (select distinct dep from tablename) t2 ON t1.dep <> t2.dep
order by t2.dep
```

Where `||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Perhaps MS SQL Server may has something else?

```
SQL>create table tablename (emp varchar(10), dep varchar(10));
SQL>insert into tablename values ('John','IT');
SQL>insert into tablename values ('Helen','HR');
SQL>insert into tablename values ('Doris','IT');
SQL>insert into tablename values ('Peter','SALES');
SQL>insert into tablename values ('Paul','SALES');
SQL>insert into tablename values ('Joane','HR');
SQL>select t1.emp, t1.dep, 'not ' || t2.dep
SQL&    from tablename t1
SQL&      join (select distinct dep from tablename) t2 ON t1.dep <> t2.dep
SQL&    order by t2.dep
SQL&;
emp        dep
========== ========== ==============
John       IT         not HR
Doris      IT         not HR
Peter      SALES      not HR
Paul       SALES      not HR
Helen      HR         not IT
Peter      SALES      not IT
Paul       SALES      not IT
Joane      HR         not IT
John       IT         not SALES
Helen      HR         not SALES
Doris      IT         not SALES
Joane      HR         not SALES

                 12 rows found
```

You can do `LOWER(t2.dep)` if you want the department name in lower case.